# Solving state-space function with using of Runge-Kutta method

Tags: control-theory, runge-kutta-methods

I need to implement my own integration routine that will take state space function $f$, free variable $t$, and initial state $x(0)$ as input and produce the solution $x(t)$ as output. I thought that using Runge-Kutta method will be great. But I cannot understand how to apply it to the state-space function matrix.
$$\dot{x}=f(t,x)$$
$$\dot{x}=A\cdot{x}$$
I have only $A$ matrix. How can I apply Runge-Kutta method?
For example, could you provide step-by-step solution for:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
-10 & -5 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a system $\dot{x} = f(x)$ with

$$
f(x) = A x = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
-10 & -5 & -2
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
-10 x_1 - 5 x_2 - 2 x_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The formula for Runge Kutta with step size $h$ is:

$$
\begin{align}
k_1 &= f(x(t)) \\
k_2 &= f(x(t) + \frac{h}{2}k_1) \\
k_3 &= f(x(t) + \frac{h}{2}k_2) \\
k_4 &= f(x(t) + h k_3) \\
x(t + h) &= x(t) + \frac{h}{6}(k_1 + 2 k_2 + 2 k_3 + k_4)
\end{align}
$$

So all you need to do is choose a step size $h$ and initial condition $x(0) = x_0$.

---

For example use $h = 0.01$ and

$$
x_0 = \begin{pmatrix}
5 \\
-2 \\
3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Insert this:

$$
\begin{align}
k_1 &= f(x_0) = \begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\
3 \\
-46
\end{pmatrix} \\
k_2 &= f(x_0 + \frac{h}{2}k_1) = \begin{pmatrix}
-1.985 \\
2.77 \\
-45.515
\end{pmatrix} \\
k_3 &= f(x_0 + \frac{h}{2}k_2) = \begin{pmatrix}
-1.98615 \\
2.772425 \\
-45.51485
\end{pmatrix} \\
k_4 &= f(x_0 + h k_3) = \begin{pmatrix}
-1.97227575 \\
2.5448515 \\
-45.02970925
\end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align}
$$

And so:

$$
x(0.01) = x(0) + \frac{0.01}{6}(k_1 + 2 k_2 + 2 k_3 + k_4) = \begin{pmatrix}
4.98014237375 \\
-1.972283830833333 \\
2.544850984583333
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If you repeat this 500 times you get:

[image]

If you simulate even longer you can see this is an undamped oscillation which makes sense because the three eigenvalues of $A$ are $-2, \sqrt{5}i, -\sqrt{5}i$.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that this is the forth order Runge-Kutta method. But there are also other order Runge-Kutta methods. And for LTI systems one can also combine all these steps such that $x(t+h) = A_d\,x(t)$ with $A_d$ a truncated Taylor series of $e^{A\,h}$.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen True, but method with $A_d$ is not really a Runge-Kutta method anymore, right?

Comment: but for LTI systems the resulting calculated value for $x(t+h)$ is the same. But you are correct that if the goal is to write your own integration routine, then calculating $A_d$ would not work in general.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I don't think this is correct, they are not the same. The $A_d$ method is exact while Runge-Kutta is approximation only. Take $A = -1, x_0 = 2$ and $h = 10$. Then $A_d = \exp(-10)$ and $A_d x_0 = 2 \exp(-10) \approx 0.00009079$ but one step Runge Kutta is $582$ which is quite wrong. Only for $h$ small enough they are approximate the same. But the Runge Kutta method has the advantage that it works for nonlinear systems (and is better for high order linear systems).

Comment: You need to use a truncated Taylor series of $e^{A\,h}$ and the truncation term depends on the order of the Runge-Kutta method. So for the forth order one gets $$A_d = I + A\,h + A^2 \frac{h^2}{2} + A^3 \frac{h^3}{6} + A^4 \frac{h^4}{24}$$ which for $A=-1$ and $h=10$ yields $A_d = 291$, thus also $A_d\,x_0 = 582$.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I see, I missed that you meant the truncated Taylor series.